# Is the term "24 inch gear" universal (in the context of fixies)?

Tags: terminology

Recently the group I ride with has included more fixie riders than I'm used to, and there's a phrase which was initially puzzling but makes perfect sense: the 24-inch gear.  I've hidden the meaning under a spoiler so readers get the experience I did.

> 24 inches is two feet, i.e. walking. (we have lots of hills, some quite steep)

I think we're all familiar with the term "gear inches" to describe the equivalent diameter of a directly driven wheel - this question is specifically about the 24" gear (not low gears in general as you'll see if you look at the spoiler).

Other experienced riders, including those with fixed-gear experience hadn't come across it, and it doesn't seem common on the web (most hits are UK long-distance riders like the ones I ride with, but there are lots of sales of bikes with gears and 24" frames to bury the hits).  Is this a universal term, or localised?

Comment: I hadn’t heard it, but I like it!

Comment: First I've heard it, but I don't ride a fixie.

Comment: My dad has numerous phrases acquired over a near century of being a "good 'ol boy" from the midwest, U.S. When us kids asked about the possibility of a car ride that amounted to a ridiculously short distance of 8-10 blocks, he often told us to, "ride shanks' ponies!"  This referred to our feet (as a shank is a butcher's term for the leg/shoulder of an animal), and he meant get to steppin 'cause walking was the only way we were gonna get there.

Comment: This sounds like some variation on rhyming slang.   A similar interpretation, the average pace for a grown adult is around 80-85 cm.  When pushing your bike it will be less, approximately 2 feet per step, or less as it gets really steep.  So an alliteration of two feet going two feet at a time.     Perhaps someone had too much time on a boring ride and got creative with words?

Comment: @Criggie I think it's simpler than that, just using those 2 feet as your drive gear. It also happens to be close enough to a steep hill ratio to be plausible. The use of feet and inches suggests a US or UK use rather than somewhere using modern units, but so far it doesn't seem widespread even there.

Comment: "24-inch gear" (more properly "24 gear inches") refers to the gear ratio, and it means that the bike will move the same distance in one turn of the crank that it would move if the crank were directly attached to a wheel of that diameter.  This is well-established terminology well-known to the bicycle cognoscenti, and it dates back to the "penny-farthing" bicycle.

Comment: By the way, a 24-inch diameter wheel does not give you 2 feet rolling distance.  You get about 6 1/4 feet.

Comment: @DanielRHicks wouldn't that mean that the wheel has a 24 inch circumference? The term 'gear-inches' would not make any sense in the days of direct drive penny farthings. A penny farthing with a 0.7 m wheel diametre would have more than 2 m of circumference, that would be about 86 inches! By the same token, a wheel with 24 in circumference would only have a diametre of less than 8 in.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I retract the previous comment in most parts. I've not realized until now that gear inches != evolvement. Haven't noticed the difference yet since the former is given in such unusual units. (Don't retract the penny-farthing comment. Gear inches make only sense in a time where geared bicycles exist. Since geared bicycles preceded all other geared moving machines the term cannot be newer.)

Comment: @gschenk - And a 24-inch gear is way low -- not practical for normal riding.

Comment: (As has been said several times, the term "gear inches" refers to the size of the wheel on a penny farthing that would be equivalent in effort/gear ratio to a particular gear configuration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this seem new to everyone here I've done a little more digging myself.  It seems to be an Audax (Randonneuring) thing, maybe with our longer rides we have more time to ponder wordplay. Here are some examples.  I've been very careful to select those where the meaning is absolutely certain; as has been pointed out in comments and other answers, 24 gear-inches is a reasonable low gear on a bike with many to choose from (my tourer's lowest gear is 26 gear-inches, while my hybrid's is 22) so I wanted to avoid citing sources that could even possibly mean this more conventional sense.

Most of the unambiguous hits I've found are from the British Audax scene, such as ["if you insist on riding fixed there's nothing here that would require the use of a '24 inch gear' (IE 2 feet!)"](http://www.delphcyclist.info/MerePerm.html) and ["Determined not to be beaten and resorting to the fabled '24 inch gear'"](https://issuu.com/audax-uk/docs/2011_may_arrivee) with quite a few relating to Paris-Brest-Paris ["Halfway I dismount and change to the 24 inch gear,"](https://yacf.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=92609.150).  One  quote  that could be referring to some of my club [" Even the mental nutter fixie audaxers I know realise there's no shame in utilising the 24 inch gear (2 feet) on a really steep hill - the payoff is gearing that is correct for the rest of the ride."](https://www.bikeradar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12829584)

Some are unambiguously American; these seem more likely to explain the term ["I WILL, at a couple points be using my 24 inch gear (a clever way of saying I’ll be using my two feet, aka walking … pretty clever eh?)"](https://drcodfish.blogspot.com/2011_05_29_archive.html?m=0), ["Some folks say "I've got two speeds: riding and walking." Others use the mathematical expression "dropping to the 24-inch gear." Twenty-four inches equals two feet. Sometimes, we get by with our own two feet."](https://kentsbike.blogspot.com/2010/04/climbing-in-24-inch-gear.html).  All the American hits I can find are from 2010-11, while definitely British uses found in a simple Google search range from 2008 to 2017.

Answer (score 0):

"Gear inches" is universal enough [to have a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear_inches):

> Gear inches is one of several relative measures of bicycle gearing, giving an indication of the mechanical advantage of different gears. Values for 'gear inches' typically range from 20 (very low gearing) via 70 (medium gearing) to 125 (very high gearing); as in a car, low gearing is for going up hills and high gearing is for going fast.
>
> 'Gear inches' is actually the diameter in inches of the drive wheel of a penny-farthing bicycle with equivalent gearing.

Comment: There's nothing incorrect in this answer, but it makes no reference to the "24 inch" aspect that's the important part of the question

Comment: @ChrisH Explain how the "24 inch" aspect is important.

Comment: Have you read the spoiler? I understand gear inches but I'm trying to find out whether this particular term is widespread. To put it another way, whatever cogs you put on your single speed, you've always got a 24" gear. Have you ever heard of this?

Comment: @AndrewHenle The question is _not_ asking for an explanation of gear-inches. It's asking specifically about whether the phrase "24-inch gear" (which does not mean "a gearing that gives 24 gear-inches") is in use outside the asker's own community.

Comment: @ChrisH -- Because you've never heard the term "24-inch gear" does not mean the term is invalid.  Yes, in that form it is ambiguous -- unclear whether one means a gear combo that produces an effective "24 gear inches" or instead means a sprocket 24 inches in diameter.  But since the latter is too big to fit on a bicycle the ambiguity is easily resolved.

Comment: Here is a very early use of the "nn inch gear" terminology: https://books.google.com/books?id=JgcAAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22inch+gear%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNuvfS-IngAhUBG6wKHWbpD6oQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22inch%20gear%22&f=false

Comment: From 1992: https://books.google.com/books?id=0Kb4lbPxLL4C&pg=PA17&dq=%22inch+gear%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirpbGW-YngAhUSPK0KHaHaCmo4ChDoAQg3MAM#v=onepage&q=%22inch%20gear%22&f=false

Comment: @DanielRHicks in this case it's not actually a gear combo. What I'd never heard until recently was using it to mean propelling a bike by walking (as there are 12 inches per foot) and definitely not a literal 24 gear-inch drivetrain. And it seems like no one else has come across it either, even though once it clicked it was fairly obvious. Hopefully now it's clear why *nn inch gear* is irrelevant to my question for values of nn other than twenty four. I didn't want to spoil the wordplay when I wrote the question.

Comment: ... One of the two web hits I found: 'I dismounted and engaged my 24" gear '

Comment: @ChrisH - Ok, that is NOT well-established terminology, and it's clearly a "play" on the standard gear-inch terminology.

Answer (score 0):

24 gear inches would be about the same as a 700c or 26" wheel with a 30 tooth chainring and a 32 tooth rear cog.   This combination would **never** be used on a fixie or singlespeed, it's just impossibly low.

Normally a fixie would be around 70 gear inches, with 60-75 being a reasonable range.  More is hard to get started and less will spin out easily.

This phrase does not feature in google's [ngram viewer - the nearest is "gear inches"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gear+inches%2Cgear-inches%2C+gear+inch%2Cgear-inch&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgear%20inches%3B%2Cc0)

This phrase also doesn't feature as anything local in New Zealand.

---

I have a folding bike with 20" wheels and 3x8 gearing, when in a 26:32 gearing that returns a low-low 15 gear inches.   This combination cannot be ridden on the flat - my legs spin out and I'm pedalling 100 RPM at 5 km/h.   On a steep hill the primary challenge is to keep going upward and stay balanced on the bike.    Such low gear-inch values would be only practical on the steep slopes and never on the flat.  Even towing heavy trailers on the flat I've never had to drop below 40 gear inches.